# Legacy VBA Solutions are not working in Office 2007

Tags: vba, ms-office, add-in, powerpoint

Folks,

An existing system that was based on VBA was installed on a machine that has Office 2007 and it didn't work, the issues I faced are :

1. A PowerPoint Add-in (.PPA) is no longer able to create the custom buttons in the shortcut menu, did Office 2007 change the commandbar names ?
2. The MSI (written in Wix) didn't install the files in XLStart folder as it was doing so in Office 2003, did Office 2007 use a new name for XLStart or another mechanism ?

Any advice on how to troubleshoot the issues above is highly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

For issue one, I think you are going to be stuck modifying the add-in to cooperate with the ribbon.

For issue two, I suspect that the start up location was hard coded. If that is the case, try writing to Excel.Application.StartupPath (You will need to set a reference to Excel if you are doing this from PowerPoint.)

Answer (score 2):

Have you ensured that you are using a trusted location or a certified project?

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/help/HA100319991033.aspx

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/206637

Answer (score 2):

On point 1:

> We understand that the intention is
>   for you to customize the right-click
>   menus with custom actions to navigate
>   through the application and perform
>   various tasks, however, right-click
>   menu creation and functionality is not
>   a feature in Power Point 2007. There
>   is currently no upgrade path for
>   previous Power Point solutions that
>   have customized right click menu
>   functionality. All previous Power
>   Point solutions using this
>   functionality will need to implement
>   the Ribbon into their solution to
>   drive user choices.

http://blogs.msdn.com/acoat/archive/2008/05/16/unable-to-customise-context-menus-in-powerpoint-2007.aspx